# Including our method to the integer class

Tags: ruby, methods, module

Is it possible in Ruby to create a module which will have one method (for example: a math method for computing lcd), and include that method to Integer class, so that I can do after something like this

```
6.lcd(3)
```

If it's possible, how can I include it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simply do something like this, without using a module:

```
class Fixnum
  def lcd(nr)
    self * nr
  end
end

puts 3.lcd(2) # -> 6
```

Answer (score 3):

You could add the `lcd` method directly to the Integer class, although you should be careful monkey patching Ruby core classes like this. Sometimes it makes sense though:

```
class Fixnum
  def lcd(argument)
    # do something here
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3):

Ruby language is designed to be completely modifiable and extensible. The first option at your disposal was outlined by andmcgregor:

```
class Integer
  def lcd arg
    # do something
  end
end
```

The second option is to create a module:

```
module Foobar
  def lcd arg
    # do something
  end
end

class Integer
  include Foobar
end
```

This option is considered a bit cleaner. The third option is to create a refinement:

```
module Foobar
  refine Integer do
    def lcd arg
      # do something
    end
  end
end

using Foobar
```

This option is the cleanest one.